# QMessageBox with a countdown timer

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I wanted to know what would be the best approach of adding a countdown timer to a `QMessageBox` ? For instance when a message box is displayed the countdown timer starts for say 5 seconds. If the user doesn't respond to the Message box the message box picks up a default choice.

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this:

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTimer>

class TimedMessageBox : public QMessageBox
{
Q_OBJECT

public:       
   TimedMessageBox(int timeoutSeconds, const QString & title, const QString & text, Icon icon, int button0, int button1, int button2, QWidget * parent, WindowFlags flags = (WindowFlags)Dialog|MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint) 
      : QMessageBox(title, text, icon, button0, button1, button2, parent, flags)
      , _timeoutSeconds(timeoutSeconds+1)
      , _text(text)
   {
      connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Tick()));
      _timer.setInterval(1000);
   }

   virtual void showEvent(QShowEvent * e)
   {
      QMessageBox::showEvent(e);
      Tick();
      _timer.start();
   }

private slots:
   void Tick()
   {
      if (--_timeoutSeconds >= 0) setText(_text.arg(_timeoutSeconds));
      else
      {
         _timer.stop();
         defaultButton()->animateClick();
      }
   }

private:
   QString _text;
   int _timeoutSeconds;
   QTimer _timer;
};
```

[...]

```
TimedMessageBox * tmb = new TimedMessageBox(10, tr("Timed Message Box"), tr("%1 seconds to go..."), QMessageBox::Warning, QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Default, QMessageBox::Cancel, QMessageBox::NoButton, this);
int ret = tmb->exec();
delete tmb;
printf("ret=%i\n", ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `QTimer::singleShot` with either `close()`, `accept()` or `reject()` slots if you don't need to display the timeout. If you need, then subclass `QMessageBox` or `QDialog` and reimplement methods as you want them to be, e.g. reimplement `QObject::timerEvent` to make text update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message box to display the timer value I think you're better off making your own `QDialog` subclass. Otherwise it sounds simple - display your message with `show`, start the timer, connect to the `timeout` slot and manipulate your dialog.